# Dictionary seems a bit off and missing values when updating value from loop

Tags: python

So I've got a list of areas and a list of targets, what I'm trying to do is just get the closest area to that target and the distance from it using haversine.
The problem I'm having is that when I'm getting the final dictionary it's not got all the records in there, I suspect something is just not being captured properly and that's jumbling the order up but having trouble figuring out where that is.

Here's my code, let me know if it's not very clear

```
#Main dictionary with results
center_dict = dict()
for index, row in targets.iterrows():
    #latitude and longitude columns for the targets
    p_lat = row[9]
    p_lon = row[10]
    #name of the target, to be primary key of dict
    name = row[0]
    distances = dict()
    #loop of the areas to map against
    for ind, r in pins.iterrows():
        #longitude and latitude data for those areas
        r_lat = r[2]
        r_lon = r[3]
        #calling haversine function that returns a distance in miles
        distance = haversine(p_lon, p_lat, r_lon, r_lat)
        #adding distance to the distances dict with the location name as a key
        distances[r[0]] = distance
    #taking minimum value from dict and the key for this
    closest = min(distances, key=distances.get)
    closest_value = min(distances.values())
    #adding the two above to the list as well as a unique id for them which is in the data
    center_dict[name] = {row[1], closest, closest_value}
```

Comment: What are `targets`, `pins`, etc?  This question would benefit from a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure that the `name` value (from `row[0]`) is unique for every element of `targets`?  If not, elements of `center_dict` will overwrite previous ones.  (That's the only way that `center_dict` could end up with a smaller size than `targets`.)